# Miner not updated to Muir Glacier. Coins now in Ice-Age-Chain(?)

Tags: hardforks, muir-glacier

What happens if a miner processes my transaction that has not updated to Muir Glacier? Is it possible that I loose coins because the miner is still on the old chain so that the coins are now on the chain that ends up in ice age?

I am worried because I sent coins from an exchange to my wallet a couple of blocks after the fork (around 9'200'010). Maybe it was too early because some miners or infrastructure providers weren't updated at that time. According to "https://ethernodes.org/muir_glacier" still a lot of miners haven't confirmed the update.

So in general: could someone loose coins when doing transactions closely around the hard fork block height?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you shouldn't have any problem. Fork are designed to cause minimal or no disruption for 
most users.

In particular Muir Glacier you shouldn't be able to lose coins. At most you have to re-send the transaction.